# Control airflow task parallelism per dag for specific tasks?

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to control the parallelism for particular tasks in an airflow dag? Eg. say I have a dag definition like...

```py
for dataset in list_of_datasets:
    # some simple operation
    task_1 = BashOperator(task_id=f'task_1_{dataset.name}', ...)
    # load intensive operation
    task_2 = BashOperator()
    # another simple operation
    task_3 = BashOperator()

    task_1 >> task_2 >> task_3
```

Is there a way to have something where task_1 can have, say, 5 of its kind running in a dag instance, while only 2 instances of task_2 may be running in a dag instance (also implying that if there are 2 instances of task_2 already running, then only 3 instances of task_1 can run)? Any other common ways to work around this kind of requirement (I imagine this must come up often for pipelines)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From discussions on the apache airflow email list...

You can use pools (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#pools) to limit how many tasks can be run in parallel for given pool.

So you can create named "pools" with task count limits (via the webserver admin menu) 
[image]
and then assign those tasks to those pools in a dag definition file when they are created

```py
for dataset in datasets:
high_load_task = BashOperator(
            task_id='high_load_task_%s' % dataset["id"],
            bash_command='some_command',
            pool='example_pool',
            trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
            dag=dag)
```

Also...

> There is another way to limit parallelism of tasks - applicable for example in cases where you have different kinds of machines with different capabilities (for example with/without GPU). You **can have some affinities defined between tasks and actual machines that are executing them** - in Celery executor you *can define queues in your celery configuration and you can assign your task to one of the queues*. Then you can have a number of workers/slots defined for all machines in the queue and as effect you can also limit parallelism of the tasks this way: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#queues